# Open a file (.mdb file in Access) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to open a mdb file through VB.NET

Currently, I use:

```
retval = shell("explorer.exe " & filename)
```

where filename includes the path.
It should open the mdb file in Microsoft Access.

This works fine on Windows 7 (my system), but when I try it on Windows XP (client machine) it comes up with the file download security warning dialog asking to Open, Save or Cancel. If I click Open it presents the same dialog but now with Save and Cancel only.

I am sure there is a quick and easy way to open a file in its proper program through VB.NET. I know I can open the database using Interop, but I don't want to go down that route.

Thanks

Comment: Use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Process.Start` to launch a program.  Some good examples here:  http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start-vbnet

For example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("database.mdb")
```